# The declaration was marked as deprecated for couchbase.Cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, couchbase

I am trying to configure couchbase to my nodejs as a database, but it seems there is an issue with couchbase.Cluster

This is what it gives me when I hover over it.
[The signature '(connStr: string, options?: ConnectOptions | undefined): Cluster' of 'couchbase.Cluster' is deprecated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55Tyq.png)

I looked up the problem, some said it might be related to type script, but I disabled it, and still no outcome. I also tried to install older versions of Typescript, still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the connect method instead.

From your screenshot, the @deprecated comment tells you to "use the static sdk-level connect method instead". In practice it looks like this:

```
import {
  Cluster,
  connect,
  ConnectOptions
} from 'couchbase'

const clusterConnStr: string =
    'couchbases://yourConnectionString'
  const username: string = 'username'
  const password: string = 'Password!123'
  const bucketName: string = 'travel-sample'

  const connectOptions: ConnectOptions = {
    username: username,
    password: password,
    // Sets a pre-configured profile called "wanDevelopment" to help avoid latency issues
    // when accessing Capella from a different Wide Area Network
    // or Availability Zone (e.g. your laptop).
    configProfile: 'wanDevelopment'
  }

  const cluster: Cluster = await connect(clusterConnStr, connectOptions)
```